# centos 7 & SELinux & ldconfig

Tags: vps, centos7, selinux

Have Centos 7 virtual instance running on a shared host. They using VMWare vSphere hypervisor.
It is a customized minimal install plus openssh and vmware tools. All updates applied. SELinux is installed but in disabled mode by default.

What i did is set permissive mode in selinux config and rebooted. After all reboots there are 8 permissions denial reported by selinux, all releated with ldconfig.

Tried to 
relabel entire file system  and temporary remove `ld.so.conf` and `ld.so.conf.d` but nothing changed.

`1. 2016-03-25 08:17:03 ldconfig system_u:system_r:ldconfig_t:s0 59 fifo_file write system_u:object_r:initrc_tmp_t:s0 denied 16
2. 2016-03-25 08:17:03 ldconfig system_u:system_r:ldconfig_t:s0 257 dir read system_u:object_r:initrc_tmp_t:s0 denied 17
3. 2016-03-25 08:17:03 ldconfig system_u:system_r:ldconfig_t:s0 2 dir write system_u:object_r:initrc_tmp_t:s0 denied 18
4. 2016-03-25 08:17:03 ldconfig system_u:system_r:ldconfig_t:s0 2 dir add_name system_u:object_r:initrc_tmp_t:s0 denied 18
5. 2016-03-25 08:17:03 ldconfig system_u:system_r:ldconfig_t:s0 2 file create system_u:object_r:initrc_tmp_t:s0 denied 18
6. 2016-03-25 08:17:03 ldconfig system_u:system_r:ldconfig_t:s0 90 file setattr system_u:object_r:initrc_tmp_t:s0 denied 19
7. 2016-03-25 08:17:03 ldconfig system_u:system_r:ldconfig_t:s0 82 dir remove_name system_u:object_r:initrc_tmp_t:s0 denied 20
8. 2016-03-25 08:17:03 ldconfig system_u:system_r:ldconfig_t:s0 82 file rename system_u:object_r:initrc_tmp_t:s0 denied 20`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved myself while become semi pro with ldconfig but the problem was not there.
Solution is simple and requires not additional knowledge, just to use `open-wm-tools` from base repo.
`vmware-uninstall-tools.pl`
`yum install open-vm-tools`
`reboot`
and all fine now
[guide to install CentOS 7 in a virtual machine by vmware](http://partnerweb.vmware.com/GOSIG/CentOS_7.html)